# How do I pass integers?

Tags: java, android

I'm relatively new to Android and wanted to practice using it. How do I pass integers in the app? I wanted to build a little combat game where I have a set skill point of `20` and wanted to pass these points to certain attributes. I don't think I can do it through a `TextView` since hard coding is bad. So essentially my main question is, do I use it through `EditText`? If so, how?  Below is a picture of what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks a lot for your time. 
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7PNh.png

Comment: Can you please share your java code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you exactly want, but :

- [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) is a widget to display a string (or any value converted to string)
- [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText) is a widget to enter a value

Comment: So basically I wanted to just display that I have 20 skill points and when I press the + button it’ll add onto Health and subtract my points after I click it. So I’m guessing Edit Text isn’t what I need? Textview seems more like it because I want it to display 20.

Comment: Yes, TextView is the one you want

Comment: @RyanP, if the answer suits you, please indicate it in order to be "community spirit" compliant